# Insert data from picture feature

Tags: excel, vba

It's possible to use this new feature from VBA?
I'm planning to use on my userform, analyzing the print from clipboard and transform in data directly to worksheet.

[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-data-from-picture](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-data-from-picture-3c1bb58d-2c59-4bc0-b04a-a671a6868fd7#:%7E:text=Import%20data%20from%20a%20sample,convert%20the%20picture%20to%20data.)

I've been trying find this feature from the references or applications, but there's nothing...

Comment: It does not appear to be something you can control with code.

Comment: You can try using the VBA macro recorder available in Excel to find properties and methods required to get the job done.